# array_diff gives Array to String conversion error in drupal

Tags: php, arrays, drupal-7, array-difference

I am experiencing a weird error from an array_diff statement. The statement is:

`$query = array_diff($params, array('f' => array()));`

and the `var_dump` of the `$params` is `array(1) { ["f"]=> array(0) { } }`

This happens in a drupal module called `Islandora_solr_search` and I get the following error message twice like below

> Notice: Array to string conversion in IslandoraSolrResults->setBreadcrumbs() (line 427 of /var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/islandora_solr_search/includes/results.inc).
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in IslandoraSolrResults->setBreadcrumbs() (line 427 of /var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/islandora_solr_search/includes/results.inc).

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

array_diff throws notice errors when it finds an array inside an array. See the [comment by Michiel Thalen](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff.php#108204)

I may assume that you're running php 5.4 or higher. You can see it by yourself, by checking your array_diff statement in the [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) (you can switch php versions there)

There's also a discussion in [Drupal forums](https://drupal.org/node/1511396)

As a quickfix I suggest this:

```
$query = @array_diff($params, array('f' => array()));
```

And in case you're going to use array_diff function with deep arrays, there are plenty
of solutions on the net, including official php.net resource.